# Rendering scene on texture necessary in order to do post processing?

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, rendering, post-processing

Is it necessary to render a scene to a texture which is then being used on a quad, covering the whole frame in order to be able to do post processing stuff? Is it because otherwise you would not be able to have the rendered image as a whole because the shader program would automatically render the image on the screen without it being possible to be edited inbetween?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to render a scene to a texture which is then being used on a quad

Yes and no. Yes, you need to render the scene to a texture. But with Compute Shaders, you don't have to render the texture to a quad.

The reason why you need to render to a texture is that you usually need to fully rendered image for the post processing effect. But this is not possible in the first render pass since you don't have access to neighbor fragments and you also wouldn't see fragments that are written after the the current one.

As @Spektre noted in a comment, the second major reason why render to texture is needed is that the OpenGL pipeline can not read actual rendering target so we need to separate processing into passes so we can read what was rendered.

Comment: +1 I would just add that the major reason is That OpenGL pipeline can not read actual rendering target so we need to separate processing into passes so we can read what was rendered... `access to neighbor fragments` is not always needed for processing.